# Greenbone/GVM (Kali Linux) scan config error message

Tags: troubleshooting

I use VirtualBox Kali Linux 2020.4. I recently installed Greenbone Vulnerability Assistant. Whenever I click on **Scans > Tasks > New Task**, the **Scan Config** drop down menu is not populated. When I click Save, it gives me this error message:

`Failed to find config 'daba56c8-73ec-11df-a475-002264764cea'`

When I click on **Configuration > Scan Configs**, it shows "No Scan Configs available".

How do I import **Scan Configs**? From reading up on it, there are supposed to be default scan configs pre-installed, is that correct? What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I was missing the default scan configuration in the Configuration > Scan Configs section as well. I entered the following command into the command line:

> sudo gvm-feed-update

It took a very long time to update. After it did, I waited for about 5 minutes and the Scan Configs page now displayed the 7 default configs. This solved my problem and I can now create scans. This is how it looks:

[image]

I think this may be because Target creation initially prompts the default scan configs:

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The `gvm-feed-update` worked also for Kali 2022.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this thread is a bit old but I want to share my experience. I'm starting my career to be a PT and preparing my tools. I'm installing OpenVAS on Kali 2022.3 running on VirtualBox. I followed the instructions on how-to install religiously. After successfully installing and running I am getting the error:

Failed to find config 'daba56c8-73ec-11df-a475-002264764cea

Whatever steps I missed causes this error. I can't find an exact solution to the problem after lengthy search. I came across to the Youtube clip below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7SrS4qDzM0 (Rhyno Cybersecurity)

All I need to have is patience! The CVE, NVT, etc updates took me an overnight to complete. And after I woke up in the morning, I ran OpenVAS did a task on DVWA and after 39 minutes I get my results.

I'm doing my happy dance now.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/424391)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the import icon on the top left: "Import Scan Config".

The default config files are located in `/var/lib/gvm/data-objects/gvmd/20.08/configs` but unfortunately you cannot import those, the import works only on something exported from Greenbone Security Assistant using the icons on the right: "Export Scan Config". I had the same problem after installing `openvas` on Kali and I managed to import the scan configs exported from another installation of `openvas`.

The "Export Scan Config" should have the same username as the one doing the import. You can fix that by manually editing the xml files after export. Look for tags owner followed by name.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from
[Can't create a scan config (failed to find config)](https://community.greenbone.net/t/cant-create-a-scan-config-failed-to-find-config/5509/16):

> Entering

```
sudo runuser -u _gvm – gvmd --get-scanners
```

should give you as output the list of your scanners;
the first column, if I remember well, should be the scanner ID.

Then, equivalently, entering:

```
sudo runuser -u _gvm – gvmd --get-users --verbose
```

should give you the list of your users (most likely you’re using “admin”), including their IDs.

Finally, entering:

```
sudo runuser -u _gvm – gvmd --modify-scanner [scanner id] --value [user id]
```

should do the trick.

Again, please consider that I’m not an expert, and this is only what solved my own problem, which, although showing the same error message, maybe had different “root causes”…

As said before, I just started from some instructions reported above in the thread, making a change because something was telling me that probably my user was not owner or was not “connected to” my scanner.

I hope this helps…

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but in my case my scan configs existed.
*FIX*
All I did was to run "gvm-feed-update" (took about 5mins), after that my scans were successful.